# Angular router : how to redirect to a component based on a part of the routerlink

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

In my Angular app

i ve this routing file :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "/my-default-page",
        pathMatch: "full"
      },
      {
        path: "reset_password",
        component: ResetPassword,
        canActivate: [MyAuthGuard],
        children: [{ path: "**", redirectTo: "/reset_password" }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
];
```

i want to not pass by a redirection , and that when the route : would be soemthing like this :

```
/reset_password/blabalabla
```

it would not redirect me but simply load the component  **ResetPassword** and keeps the url as it is

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: can you please elaborate the issue, what is happening, what is required, what is redirect you are mentioning? with a stackblitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use route parameters. You then don't need any children routes.

```
{
    path: "reset_password/:id",
    component: ResetPassword,
    canActivate: [MyAuthGuard]
  }
```

Your link will remain the same and if you want you can retrieve this parameter from the link using the following code in your ResetPassword component

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit():void{
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```